# Java Stream Api strings manipulation

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

I have some list of words `List<String> strings` I have to make a word out of most frequent letters on each position.

For example for `strings = {"qwerty", "qwer" , "ab", "bab"}` the result would be "qwer"

Letters that appear once do not count

I came up to idea of creating a list

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> list;
```

Its size is equal to the string in `strings` of maximal size and the map would count number of characters on the position

```
IntStream.range(0, strings.stream().max(String::compareTo).get().length()) 
    .forEachOrdered(i -> {
        strings.stream().forEach(s -> {
            if (s.length()>i){
                Map<String,Integer> temp = list.get(i);
                String character = s.charAt(i) + "";
                Integer value = temp.get(character) == null ? 0 : temp.get(character) + 1;
                temp.put(character, value);
                list.add(i, temp);
            }
        });
    });
```

Have no idea why id doesn't work

Comment: But in your example `strings` is an array.

Comment: I don't get your example. Shouldn't the result be "qwerty" since 't' and 'y' are the most frequent characters for positions 5,6?

Comment: You need to provide further examples that help clarify what exactly the problem is

Comment: What about "ab".  They appear more than once.

Comment: @NickZiebert: He wants a string comprised from the most frequent character at each position. There are two 'q' characters at position one. Therefore first character of the result should be q.

Comment: `max(String::compareTo)` is equivalent to `max(Comparator.naturalOrder())`, which just happen to provide the desired result by pure luck due to the picked sample strings. What you want, is actually `strings.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).get().length()` to get the maximum string length, but it is simpler and more efficient to map to length first: `strings.stream().mapToInt(String::length).max().orElse(0)`

Answer (score 4):

Here's another approach:

```
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import static java.util.function.Function.identity;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

...

strings.stream()
    .flatMap(s -> IntStream.range(0, s.length()).mapToObj(i -> new SimpleEntry<>(i, s.charAt(i))))
    .collect(groupingBy(SimpleEntry::getKey, mapping(SimpleEntry::getValue, groupingBy(identity(), counting()))))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).get())
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

which outputs:

```
q=2
w=2
e=2
r=2
```

From the stream of strings you create a stream of entries for each character mapped with their respective positions. From there you group them by the position and you group the values so that for each position you have a Map representing the occurences of the different characters at this position.

Then you filter out the values that have a count less than 2 (your 'Letters that appear once do not count' requirement)and finally you get the most frequent letter for each remaining position.

Comment: It doesn't work.  ("qwer" , "ba", "babe", "babe", "babe", "babe"); should be babe.

Comment: @NickZiebert Yes, forgot to change the Collections.max part, will update

Comment: Who was the lemming that gave you an upvote for an answer that doesn't work.

Comment: @NickZiebert It should be working now, thanks for the comment.

Comment: List<String> strings2 = Arrays.asList("qwerty", "rwer" , "ab", "bab");

In this case, the output should be [w e r] (since we have only one q, r,a,b at first position which should not be counted according to the OP). Your code outputs: [a w e r]

Comment: BTW, I gave the up-vote for the very cool idea and nice functional implementation without using a cumbersome data structure. I think the OP needs to revise the question and make it more clear what he exactly wants.

Comment: @jrook Ok, I will update it to not take any value in case of a tie. By the way if the downvoter can explain why that would be helpful for improving the solution.

Comment: @Alexis: It is not about a tie. The OP says characters that are repeated once should not be included in the result. The character position should not matter. In the case of OP's example, 't', 'y' are not in the result since they occur only once in the list in their respective positions. In my example, all letters in position 1 occur only once hence they should be omitted from the result.

Comment: it doesn't work.   "qwer" , "qwe", "wwr", "bw", "ba", "babe" should give bwe

Comment: @jrook Ok, I misunderstood the 'Letters that appear once do not count' requirement. I thought that it would mean that you should take the second max length of all the strings and do the stuff from there. Now, I hope it should work.

Comment: @NickZiebert Yes, I think misunderstood one requirement (see above comment). The update should work, hopefully.

Comment: Cool, seems to work now.  Now could you break it up into smaller methods?  I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Can we compare this approach's efficiency to my more direct and imperative approach?

Comment: @jrook Well, my approach can benefit from parallelism. Yours, however, does not work in parallel and produce wrong results (due to concurrency issues). Then, assuming both solutions are correct, only a benchmark with different variety of inputs will tell which solution is faster.

Comment: @NickZiebert Well, I think this is as much expressive as you can get with the standards Collectors provided in JDK-8. This may be clearer when you start to be familiar with how downstream collectors works.

Comment: @AlexisC. I bet the code would become much more expressive if it was broken up into smaller methods.

Comment: @NickZiebert To be honest, I don't see what you don't find expressive. The only thing that may a bit complicated at first is `.collect(groupingBy(SimpleEntry::getKey, mapping(SimpleEntry::getValue, groupingBy(identity(), counting()))))` but with some experience using the collectors, it's finally not as hard as it seems.

Comment: @AlexisC.Great solution, nice job.  Personally, I would break it up into smaller chunks.  But I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take. For maximum length string, I used the formula given [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75807/finding-the-longest-string-and-its-length-using-java-streams).
I am assuming your string has only alphabetical characters in it. Therefore there is no need for a hashmap. An array of size 26 will do. Then I just loop over each position and find the most frequent character.

```
public class WordsWithMostFrequentChars {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] st = new String[] { "qwerty", "qwer" , "ab", "bab"};
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(st);
    List<Character> result = new ArrayList<Character>();
    int maxLength = strings.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).get().length();

    IntStream.range(0,maxLength).forEach(i -> {
        int[] freq = new int[26];
        strings.stream().forEach(s -> {
            Character c;
            if(s.length()>i) {
                c=s.charAt(i);
                freq[c - 'a'] = freq[c - 'a'] + 1;
            }
        });
        // max finder
        int max = 0;
        for (int k = 1; k < 26; k++)
            if (freq[k] > freq[max])
                max = k;

        if(freq[max]>1) result.add((char) ('a' + max));

        });

        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

Run:

```
[q, w, e, r]
```

Comment: The main diddiculty wan in usnig ONLY stream api

Comment: If the only limitation is using only Java 8 stream api, then just replace the for loops above with forEach. It should be a trivial thing to do. For max finding there are also a lot of Java 8 solutions available on SO.

You should try and ask your question more clearly and specify exactly what you want.

Comment: I thought the answer was qwer not qwerty

Comment: I updated my answer, still I do not quite understand what the OP means by "only using java 8 stream api)

Comment: If you order by the same property, you will finally query, it’s much simpler and more efficient, to map to the property first, i.e. instead of `strings.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)) .get().length()`, you can use `strings.stream().mapToInt(String::length).max().orElse(0)`

Comment: By the way, a `StringBuilder` makes a much better result type than an `ArrayList<Character>()`…